# javascript-How to use regex on json string to search datatable column in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I just used the below statement in javascript to search specific string in one column and filter the records in a data table.

```
  term = $(this).val();
  table.column(2).search(term, true, false).draw();
```

Here is my JSON string:

```
[{"userid":"2315","location":"x","details":"{\"subject‌​s\": {\"English\": [\"meena\", \"teena\"]}, \"hours\": {\"2\"}}}", 
 {"userid":"3009","location":"y","details":"{\"subjects\": {\"English\": [\"meena\"]}, \"hours\": {\"4\"}}}, 
 {"userid":"3109","location":"z","details":"{\"English\": [\"suresh\", \"divya\"]}, \"hours\": {\"4\"}}, 
 {"userid":"3209","location":"a","details":"{\"English\": [\"ramesh\", \"meena\"]}, \"hours\": {\"4\"}}, 
 {"userid":"3309","location":"b","details":"{\"subjects\": {\"English\": [\"revathi\", \"meena\"]}, \"hours\": {\"4\"}}}
]
```

Want to match any one value of "English" using regex and search with that values to filter records.Something like below.

```
regex = '"English": ["'+ '.*' +term+'.*';
table.column(3).search(regex, false, false).draw();
```

But the above statement is not working.

Can any one suggest me the correct way to write regex for this?

Comment: Don't use regex. Parse the JSON to an object and filter it.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan,can you give me a simple example?I am very new to this.

Comment: That "JSON" does not appear to be valid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

1. If the `search` method supports regular expressions and you absolutely need doing such thing, pass something like `new RegExp('"English": \\["'+ '.*' +term+'.*', 'gi')`.
2. As suggested in comments, it is not a great idea to treat JSON as a string. Excessive whitespace or escaped special characters may result into a wrong answers. You would be better off parsing the JSON and searching as needed, e.g.:

   ```
   var term = ...;
   for (var i = 0, l = rows.length; i < l; i++) {
       var row = rows[i];
       var user = JSON.parse(row);
       var details = user.details && JSON.parse(user.details);
       if (details.English && details.English.indexOf(term) !== -1) {
           // there is the searched term in the users' details
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Hi..` regex = new RegExp('"English": ["'+ '.*' +term+'.*', 'gi');` this statement throwing exception..I dont know whats wrong here.

Comment: I edited the answer, the `[` symbol must be escaped with a `\\ `  because `[` without `\\ ` declares a character class.

Comment: In the 2nd solution of yours what is 'rows'?..will it assign with json string?

Comment: `rows` is an array of strings. JSON string is in the `row`. What does your `table.column(2)` return? Is it an array?

Comment: `table.column(2)` is json object

Comment: @Andrew..with RegEXp exception is not coming now,but still it is not matching the json string

Comment: If i remove the `.*` it is working,but not finding all records.

Comment: Your RegExp searches only for the first item in the array. You would need to either make your regular expression more complex or use a proper JSON-parsing approach instead.

Comment: ok.I have tried the 2nd solution,,but where and how to give this `table.column(3).search()` statement..can you give the detailed example?